# SVM MATLAB implementation Error plotting decision boundary

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to do binary classification in MATLAB but the following code throws an error at the end.

```
   load('ex6data1.mat');

% Plot training data
plotData(X, y);



fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;

model=fitcsvm(X,y);
visualizeBoundaryLinear(X,y,model); //error shows up here i guess


fprintf('Paused');




Error window
   Error using subsref
No appropriate method, property, or field 'w' for class
'ClassificationSVM'.

Error in classreg.learning.internal.DisallowVectorOps/subsref (line
21)
                [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref',this,s);

Error in visualizeBoundaryLinear (line 7)
w = model.w;

Error in Untitled2 (line 18)
visualizeBoundaryLinear(X,y,model);
```

Note:Y is 1 for positive example and -1  for negative.

Comment: What error does matlab throw? Can you copy it under your code please?

Comment: Hi i have added it..

Comment: What does `visualizeBoundaryLinear` look like?  The error happens in that function, but `visualizeBoundaryLinear` is not part of the native MATLAB distribution.

Comment: What i want to do is plot the linear decision boundary obtained by the SVM..why is the visualizeboundarylinear function throwing an error..isnt it supposed to help me do what i want?

Comment: Yeah it's supposed to do that, but the code is happening in that function... how can we help you if we don't see what the code is doing?

Comment: This code is unnecessary. He's trying to access a `w` property of an object which doesn't have one. See my response for some more details.

Comment: I have first trained an SVM on the data with class labels -1 and 1 and stored the resulting parameters under the name 'model'. Now i want to plot the linear decision boundary...

Comment: I know what's going on.  This code you took from Andrew Ng's machine learning class.  That call to `fitcsvm` was supposed to be a call to a custom `svmTrain` file that has custom behaviour.  You're substituting it with MATLAB's own version of it, which isn't compatible with your code (currently).  As such, you can use the answer below as a start, but make sure you get the right parameters required from the result and create a new structure that conforms to what the original `svmTrain` method provided you.

Comment: svmTrain solves the primal problem and fitcsvm solves the dual problem..is that how it works? What do i do to get started if i have only the training set and nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [MATLAB documentation for `fitcsvm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html?refresh=true) you'll find that there is no property `w`, which is what's giving you your error.

You need to calculate the weights `w` yourself, since MATLAB is solving the *dual form* of the SVM. More details can be found here. Take a look at [this reference](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/support-vector-machines-the-linearly-separable-case-1.html) if you want to learn more. You can use the following formula:

```
w = zeros( size(x(1,:)) );
for i=1:N
    w = w + alpha(i)*y(i)*x(i,:);
end
```

You can calculate the `w` vector using a combination of the alpha's, which are returned in your model, and your data.

Comment: Allright..so the dual form enables us to use kernels. What are these weights exactly..what do i do if i want to plot the resulting linear decision boundary? Edit:The weights give the direction of the seperating hyperplane..so fitcsvm does not actuallly find the direction?

Comment: The weights give the direction of the seperating hyperplane..so fitcsvm does not find the weights..in which case how do i do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a formula for this procedure. Your code may look slightly different.

Comment: Okay..so since the dual problem is being solved we get the alpha vector..and the w is obtained by that linear combination. Now,since we have w we can plot the linear decision boundary..but what about the value of the intercept b..we  need to find that as well right..and how do i pass these parameters to the function plot?